# Differentiability of Complex Function and Its Conjugate at $a$

Tags: complex-analysis

> Let a complex function $f$ be differentiable at $a$. Show that $\overline{f(z)}$ is differentiable at $a$ if and only if $f'(a) = 0$.

I am given as a hint that I can use the definitions of the derivative and the conjugate.

So, starting with the assumption that the conjugate is differentiable, we need to show that $f'(a) = 0$. From this, we can see that $\lim_{z \to a} \frac{f(z) - f(a)}{z - a}$ exists. Furthermore, since $\overline{f(z)}$ is differentiable, then $\lim_{z \to a} \frac{\overline{f(z)} - \overline{f(a)}}{z - a}$ exists. The goal is to show that $f'(a) = \lim_{z \to a} \frac{f(z) - f(a)}{z - a} = 0$. However, I am not sure where to proceed from here.

For the other direction - assuming that $f'(a) = 0$ - this means that $f'(a) = \lim_{z \to a} \frac{f(z) - f(a)}{z - a} = 0$. We need to show that $\overline{f}$ is differentiable at $a$ - that is, that $\lim_{z \to a} \frac{\overline{f(z)} - \overline{f(a)}}{z - a}$ exists.

Again, I'm not sure where to proceed on these parts, and I'm not sure where the definition of the conjugate comes into play in either direction of the proof.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$f(z)=u+iv$ is differentiable at $a$ if $u_x,v_x,u_y,v_y$ are continuous and Cauchy Riemann's equation is satisfied at $a$ i.e. $u_{x} (a)=v_{y} (a),u_{y} (a)=-v_{x} (a)$
And, also, $f(z)=u+iv$ is differentiable at $a$ then Cauchy Riemann's equation is satisfied at $a$ i.e. $u_{x} (a)=v_{y} (a),u_{y} (a)=-v_{x} (a)$

We see that, the necessary and sufficient conditions for differentiability of $f$ at $a$ , must depend on the satisfaction of Cauchy Riemann's equations.

As, $f=u+iv$ is analytic, $u_x,v_x,u_y,v_y$ are all continuous.
So, we can take the sufficient and necessary condition for differentiability of $\bar{f}$ by neglecting the part of continuity of $u_x,u_y,v_x,v_y$.

So,now $\bar{f(z)}=u-iv=u+i(-v)$ is differentiable at $a$ $\iff$ $u_{x} (a)=-v_{y} (a),u_{y} (a)=v_{x} (a)$

As, $2u_{x} (a)=0 \implies u_{x} (a)=0 $
And, similarly, $v_{x} (a)=0 $

So, now, $f'(a)=u_{x} (a)+i v_{x} (a)=0 $ $\iff$ $f$ is differentiable at $a$.

Comment: Small nitpick, but the "iff" in your first sentence is false. Continuity of the partial derivatives is sufficient, but not necessary. What is necessary is real differentiability of $f$. Continuity of the partial derivatives *in an open neighborhood* implies real differentiability, but isn't strictly necessary.

Comment: @Vercassivelaunos yeah, I know that. But it is more matters with the Cauchy Riemann's equation, that's why I ignored it. But, you can see that from both sides, Cauchy Riemann's equation is obvious.